# Including the JQuery file in JSP confusion?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a `JSP` page called `main.jsp` and the **jsp page** has `three` iframes.

Each `Iframe` loads an individual `JSP`(page1.jsp , page2.jsp , page3.jsp) and each `JSP` uses a individual `JS` file consists of `JQuery` code.

Currently I included the `Jquery 1.9.1.js` in every `JSP page` ( `main.jsp`  and it's `iframe laded JSP's` ) and my project works fine .

Is this the proper way , Because I included the `Jquery 1.9.1.js` in every `JSP` .

How I can load the `Jquery 1.9.1.js` in my `main.jsp` alone and make visible to all `JSP's` .

I don't want to include the `Jquery 1.9.1.js` in every `JSP's` . I need the `Jquery 1.9.1.js` to be centralized.

Is this possible ?

Hope my question is little clear and understandable.Please don't hesitate to edit or ask questions.

Comment: Try adding jquery js only in the main file and see, the rest seems fine to me.

Comment: Getting is `$` is undefined error.

Comment: Why don't u define a set a variable for jquery in jsp and use that variable in all the iframes. You can change the jquery version anytime. Use Google CDN for jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think it is possible when you use iFrames.

Since each iframe `src` will load the new page and it runs in `its own window context`

Its not easy to use a single jQuery.js to control the behaviour for the controls inside iFrame.

So you did correct.

Still if you want, you could use different `<div>` and load the content into it. This way one jQuery will work, since all the divs are in same window context

Answer (score 1):

While using iframes you have to add jquery in each page.Each page in iframe is considered as child.If you were using divs in place of iframe then using centralized jquery1.9.1.js would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make templates `Header.jsp` and `Footer.jsp`. Then included the `Jquery 1.9.1.js` on header or footer. 
Then you can use header or footer on your `main.jsp` and on every page.